# How to rename a linked clone on vsphare with the vm configuration files

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-player, vsphere

I'd like to rename a linked clone configuration files on Vsphere.  I tried to change the VM from a datastore to another but the VM becomes not a linked clone.

I also tried to make migrating to the same datastore but it doesn't change the name on the datastore.  Is it possible to change the name of a linked clone and their configuration file?

Comment: Are you simply looking to change the name of the file of the virtual machine or are you looking to change the name of the virtual machine within your inventory?

Comment: i'm looking to change the name of the VM within my inventory also the name of the vm folder inside the datastore and their configuration files